# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Search does not work

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search

Our Sharepoint Search has stopped working from one day to another.

When trying to create a new Search Application, i defined an "admin.spsearch" admin account and a "service.spfarm" service Account in the config + created a new Application Pool.

Creation succeeded, but when i click the new Search Application, i cannot define the Scope or the Job, as it's displaying "Error: Access Denied". I'm logged in as Administrator of the Sharepoint. It doesn't let me access the Application, when filling out the login with the creds of "Admin.spsearch".

Any ideas? I also defined my own Account as Farm Administrator for testing purposes, without Success (Access denied)

Any Help is welcome. :-)

Comment: We had a similar experience on a test system. Also tried reconfiguring or recreating SearchSerivce. Nothing helped than reinstall the SharePoint Server from scratch.

Comment: Wow, that would be a real pain in the *ss, as its a productive Server and i'm a bit afraid about moving the Database and all of the content. Any clues?

Comment: to use foundation for a live system is always a risk. But first directive in using SharePoint is: don't panic. The reinstall scenario is only our experience. That does not mean that this is finally your issue. Perhaps someone else has alternating advices.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will wait for other comments. :-)